# Batch file to create a user and then assign permissions with mysql

Tags: mysql, command-line, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file to create a new user and then assign permissions to the new user.  I want to do something like this:

```
c:\mysql\bin\mysql -uroot -ppassword < CREATE USER 'username_here'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_here';
c:\mysql\bin\mysql -uroot -ppassword < GRANT ALL ON myDB.* TO 'username_here'@'localhost';
```

Problem is I get an error saying the System can not find the file specified.  I know I am calling the mysql exe from the right place because if I just do:

```
c:\mysql\bin\mysql -uroot -ppassword
```

it logs in and gives me the mysql prompt.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `--execute` option to pass one statement to the database:

```
c:\mysql\bin\mysql -uroot -ppassword --execute="CREATE USER 'username_here'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_here';"
c:\mysql\bin\mysql -uroot -ppassword --execute="GRANT ALL ON myDB.* TO 'username_here'@'localhost';"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to puts quotes around the command, otherwise the shell thinks you are giving it a file name:

```
c:\mysql\bin\mysql -uroot -ppassword < "CREATE USER 'username_here'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_here';"
c:\mysql\bin\mysql -uroot -ppassword < "GRANT ALL ON myDB.* TO 'username_here'@'localhost';"
```

Comment: That's because `<` is used to redirect input from a file, not input verbatim text to a program.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things slightly using just a single `GRANT` statement:

```
mysql mysql -uroot -ppassword --execute "GRANT ALL ON myDB.* TO username_here@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password_here';"
```

You do seem to have to specify the `mysql` database when you run it this way, and if you don't use reserved words for your username, you can avoid a few quotes.